# Не работает gem в ruby

Tags: linux, ruby, archlinux, gems, manjaro

```
gem update
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
    libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

    ruby -v -> ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

Arch Linux (Manjaro)

Ставил из pacman , потом из yaourt, оба не работают, как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Полное обновление пакетов через pamac решило вопрос.